# Migrating to Windows 7 - How will this impact my software?

Tags: c#, windows-7, windows-xp

I want to migrate to Windows 7 from XP, and I have some questions:

1. Will Oracle 10g and SQL Server 2008 work?
2. Will my C# programming (in Visual Studio 2003, 2005 and 2008) work?
3. Do I need to do anything particular before upgrading?

Comment: Check that your machine fits the specification, run the Microsoft program to check which version of Windows 7 you can upgrade to, adjust yourself to the possibility that you may have to re-install every program on your machine. This last one kept me from upgrading fron teh *Windows 7 beta* to *Windows 7 Professional*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Yes
2. Yes
3. No

Comment: In my experience the answer to #2 is "Mostly" since I have observed some weird DLL errors resulting from upgrading your OS. But otherwise an excellent answer.

Answer (score 1):

The windows 7 upgrade isn't as important as the upgrade to window's 7's .net version (3.5 I think...). Searching for the impact of .net 3.5 will prove much more fruitful. :D

Answer (score 1):

In my experience a point to take care of is that writing to various file system locations in my application had to be adjusted.

Since Windows XP users usually run as administrators, my application could nearly write everywhere. In Windows Vista/Windows 7 the UAC forces you to read the MSDN documentation in more detail to write to locations that are allowed.

The [`System.Environment.SpecialFolder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx) enumeration is very useful.

Answer (score 0):

1.yes
2.yes
3.verify that your hardware has, at least, the minimal required performance?